How to prove a Fourier transform inequality for a function with bounded support in mixed variables?
I'm working on a problem involving the Fourier transform and have encountered an inequality that I am unsure how to prove. I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance you can provide.
Let $\gamma\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ and $v\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Also $\text{supp}\gamma(\cdot,\xi)\subset U$ and $|U|<+\infty$ for all $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Prove that there exist a constant $C=C(U)>0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\mathcal{F}(\gamma(x,\cdot)v(\cdot))(x)|^{2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq C\Vert{\gamma}\Vert_{\infty}\left (\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|v(y)|dy\right),
\end{equation*}
where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform.
Initially, I tried to use Plancherel's theorem, this is
\begin{equation}
\Vert \mathcal{F}(\gamma(x,\cdot)v(\cdot)) \Vert_{L^2}=\Vert{\gamma (x,\cdot)v(\cdot)}\Vert_{L^{2}}
\end{equation}
and then use the hypothesis that $\gamma\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$. However, this idea is totally incorrect, since it is not possible to use plancherel in that case.
